# Cartesian plane points given in equation form

Tags: vector-spaces

$${x+3\over 5}={y-5\over 3}={z-11\over -3}$$

How would I determine if the above line contains the point $(1, 1, 5)$?

Couldn't $(x, y, z)$ be any value? For example $(2, 8, 4)$ than the line would contain the point.

Comment: You plug the point in, and if the equation is true, it lies on the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any point lying on a line must satisfy its equation otherwise the point doesn't lie on it.

We have 
$${x+3\over 5}={y-5\over 3}={z-11\over -3}$$

Substitute the point $(1, 1, 5)$, as follows 
$${1+3\over 5}={1-5\over 3}={5-11\over -3}$$
$${4\over 5}\neq{-4\over 3}\neq{2}$$
We find that the point $(1, 1, 5)$ doesn't satisfy the equation of the line hence it is not contained by the line

For any point $(x, y, z)$ lying on the line: $\frac{x-x_1}{a}=\frac{y-y_1}{b}=\frac{z-z_1}{c}$ must fully satisfy its equation.

Taking an example of point $(2, 8, 4)$ & above line:${x+3\over 5}={y-5\over 3}={z-11\over -3}$, substituting the coordinates we get 
$${2+3\over 5}={8-5\over 3}={4-11\over -3}$$
$$1=1\neq{7\over 3}$$
We find that the point $(2, 8, 4)$ doesn't fully satisfy the equation of the line hence it is not contained by the line

Comment: Awesome explanation!